# switch between xibs on button action

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm having difficulty in switching between xibs :(

first i was using navigationController and it worked well but i want to do it without using navigationController.

I tried presentModalViewController but it crashes my application. :((

Here is the code :

```
    myViewController *viewController = [myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    myViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController: myViewController animated:YES];
    [myViewController release];
```

It is not working, ERROR received :
GDB:Program received signal : "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myViewController *viewController = [myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController: viewController animated:YES];
```

this should work. your problem was that you declared a view controller and named it "viewController", but you were not using that. you were using the view controllers name, not the declared instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your nibName to `nil`
Enter the name of your Xib file you want to display there
Like

```
 myViewController *viewController = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nameOfYourXIB" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    myViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController: myViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: GDB:Program received signal : "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: look at your stack.on which line its crashing..?

Answer (score 0):

remove the release statement from ur code and everything will work fine.

Actually u r releasing the viewcontroller before it is shown as the superview.

```
//[myViewController release];
```

Hope this helps u...

Comment: myViewController *viewController = [myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController: viewController animated:YES];  write the above code
pass the instance object instead of the viewcontroller itself

Answer (score 0):

Don't release he controller its a global variable i suppose so just make it in nil in dealloc